# can I find if 2 users are connected on facebook or Orkut? is there any API from either to find it?

Tags: social-networking

I would like to know if I am connect another person (say jack) on Facebook or Orkut using an API. I should be able to use it on my web application.

Answer (score 1):

@Bhasker, I think FB has not come up with such an API yet, so in case you want that for your application you might want to make your own graph database, lets say using *Neo4j*, and calculate if 2 people on FB are connected. Of Course the results would be less precise but you can still do it to a certain extent.

Answer (score 0):

In facebook people are connect with friendship, so you can use facebook API or FBQL to know who you are connected with.

This is how you can get the list of your connect/friends:

```
$friends = $facebook->api_client->friends_get();
```

Comment: true, but this gets me the complete friends  list. What I am most interested in is to see if 2 people are connected or not. They maybe directly connected or through someone else. May be the API can regulate the depth of the tree.